# Install gitlab-ce on ubuntu server 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-17.04

I'm trying to install the gitlab-ce package on a system running Ubuntu server 17.04. I followed the official installation instructions [here](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu).

First I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix
```

I already had all of those installed. Then I ran:

```
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

Which also worked fine. But when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

I get the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gitlab-ce
```

I know it's possible to install gitlab on Ubuntu server 17.04, since I had already done It on a previous installation. Unfortunately I installed the OS again from scratch and I can't remember how I had installed gitlab.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I gave up with the "full" automated script, as it doesn't appear to be working with 17.04... Anyway. I grabbed the latest package from https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ce_9.3.0-ce.0_amd64.deb

```
curl -LJO https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ce_9.3.0-ce.0_amd64.deb/download
```

Installed it with the package manager

```
sudo dpkg -i gitlab-ce_9.3.0-ce.0_amd64.deb
```

Then configured it with

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Then, point your web browser at your new gitlab install and you should be good to go...

### Ubuntu 20.04.1

Incase anyone bumps back into this, while trying to gitlab on version 20.0.4 of ubuntu, life is much easier... and the instructions and automated script actually work. [GitLab-CE installation instructions](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/install)

on a fresh install of ubuntu: -

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab- ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt install gitlab-ce
```

done!

Comment: I also tried manually installing it, but I used a different file, which didntn't seem to work... Anyways, thanks for your help, this works!

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same problem (Lubuntu 17.10), after searching the gitlab forums for 2 Hours, I found [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1720).
So from what I have read: *Gitlab-ce is not supported for zesty yet.* Also the simple

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab
```

is a **wrong prompt** cause it installs a Ubuntu package created by a user named as "praveen" and **It is not officially supported by Gitlab.**

here is what I did To solve my problem:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list.save
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list
```

replace "zesty" with "xenial" (These files are root access only)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

This worked for me.
I have spent my whole afternoon for solving this problem, I hope this solution works for you too.

Prost !

EDIT: corrected spelling

Comment: In my case `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list` could not been created somehow. Maybe because I am behind a proxy. I checked the script and added the file with the content of the following page: [https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/config_file.list?os=Ubuntu&dist=zesty&source=script](https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/config_file.list?os=Ubuntu&dist=zesty&source=script). Finally changing _zesty_ to _xenial_ made i possible to install GitLab with apt.

Comment: I changed from "artful" to "xenial" and it worked.  I'm using Ubuntu 17.

Comment: I succeeded by changing "cosmic" to "bionic".

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem getting the install to run on 17.10. According to an issue on their site ( https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2851 ), the artful packages are not being built.

I did the same this as @DevX, but just changed the parameters on their setup script.

> Howler@GitLab:/tmp$ curl -LO https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh
>
> Howler@GitLab:/tmp$ sudo os=ubuntu dist=xenial bash ./script.deb.sh
>
> Howler@GitLab:/tmp$ sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce